# SQL Query - JOIN and UNION

Tags: mysql, sql

I am having trouble to answer this question :
Display the last name and client company (COMPANY) for the employees who made a sale for clients of Paris" sorted on the Company Name.

Here is my code :

```
select NAME from EMPLOYEES inner join SALES on EMPLOYEES.NO_EMPLOYEES = SALE.NO_EMPLOYEES
union
select COMPANY from SALES inner join CLIENTS on SALES.CODE_CLIENT = CLIENTS.CODE_CLIENT where CLIENTS.CITY = 'Paris'
```

Problem is that union gives me only one column... How to solve this issue ?

Thanks for your help !

Comment: Sample data and desired results would hep.

Comment: Help us help you - please share the table structures, some sample data, and the result you're trying to get for that data

Answer (score 0):

I think you just want two joins:

```
select e.NAME, c.COMPANY
from EMPLOYEES e join
     SALES s
     on e.NO_EMPLOYEES = s.NO_EMPLOYEES join
     CLIENTS c
     on s.CODE_CLIENT = c.CODE_CLIENT
where c.CITY = 'Paris';
```